# Why does this image from Artemis 1 have horizontal stripes?

Tags: imaging, data-transmission, artemis-1

[This image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Close_up_picture_of_the_lunar_surface_from_Orion.jpg) (crop shown below) from Wikipedia's article on the the Artemis I mission has some unexpected artifacts: horizontal stripes across the image that look like missing data.  I'd expect that from something like an early Pioneer probe where the spacecraft lacks the ability to store images for later transmission, but not from something modern.  Further, this is described as being from the closest approach.  Both close approaches happened above the lunar farside with no line-of-sight to Earth, so it *can't* be dropped data from a streaming transmission.

What's the cause?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer as the link describes it better:

https://space.stackexchange.com/a/61109/40489

This answer probably has what you're looking for. It should give you an idea of what resulted in such imagery.

Background:

The images come from Orions optical navigation camera, itself capable of hi-res high quality imagery but that isn't its job.

So you could say its imaging has been throttled by its software and purpose which is tracking subjects such as earth and the moon for navigation purposes (something like 100 images for each comparison), especially for when Orion is out of direct communication with earth.

So the images are low quality due to what they're looking for, not what the camera is capable of in pretty picture taking mode.